# How to implement an AI opponent in a basic Tic Tac Toe gameboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in programming. I have worked on a basic Tic Tac Toe gameboard, it works successfully. For the second phase of my assignment, I am required to implement an AI opponent however I came across several problems.

As a beginner, I need some help and guidance as to how I can fix and work on my codes of the normal Tic Tac Toe gameboard so that I can have an AI opponent.

I used HTML, CSS, and JS for my basic Tic Tac Toe gameboard. I will list all my codes below:

HTML

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="board">
      <div class="square" id="0"></div>
      <div class="square" id="1"></div>
      <div class="square" id="2"></div>
      <div class="square" id="3"></div>
      <div class="square" id="4"></div>
      <div class="square" id="5"></div>
      <div class="square" id="6"></div>
      <div class="square" id="7"></div>
      <div class="square" id="8"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="reset">Reset Game</button>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS

```
`.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square:hover {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.square.X {
  color: #ff5e5e;
}

.square.O {
  color: #0077ff;
}
`
```

JS

```
`let board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let currentPlayer = "X";
let gameOver = false;

const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

// Add click event listener to each square
squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

// Add click event listener to reset button
resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);

function handleClick(event) {
  const square = event.target;
  const index = square.getAttribute("id");

  // If square is already clicked or game is over, return
  if (board[index] !== "" || gameOver) {
    return;
  }

  // Add X or O to board and update UI
  board[index] = currentPlayer;
  square.classList.add(currentPlayer);
  square.innerHTML = currentPlayer;

  // Check for winner or tie game
  checkForWinner();
  checkForTieGame();

  // Switch current player
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
}

function checkForWinner() {
  for (let i = 0; i < winningConditions.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = winningConditions[i];
    if (board[a] === board[b] && board[b] === board[c] && board[a] !== "") {
      gameOver = true;
      highlightWinnerSquares(a, b, c);
      displayWinner(board[a]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function checkForTieGame() {
  if (!board.includes("") && !gameOver) {
    gameOver = true;
    displayTieGame();
  }
}

function highlightWinnerSquares(a, b, c) {
  document.getElementById(a).classList.add("winner");
  document.getElementById(b).classList.add("winner");
  document.getElementById(c).classList.add("winner");
}

function displayWinner(player) {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = `${player} wins!`;
}

function displayTieGame() {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = "It's a tie game!";
}

function resetGame() {
  board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  currentPlayer = "X";
  gameOver = false;

  squares.forEach(square => {
    square.classList.remove("X", "O", "winner");
    square.innerHTML = "";
  });

  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = "";
}`
```

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: You said: "I came across several problems"  — what problems?

Comment: The gameboard works perfectly, however when playing the came the AI opponent fails to comprehend.

Comment: What do you want the AI to comprehend, that it is not comprehending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the contents of `handleClick` into its own method:

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  const square = event.target;
  click(square);
}

function click(square) {
  const index = square.getAttribute("id");

  // If square is already clicked or game is over, return
  if (board[index] !== "" || gameOver) {
    return;
  }

  // Add X or O to board and update UI
  board[index] = currentPlayer;
  square.classList.add(currentPlayer);
  square.innerHTML = currentPlayer;

  // Check for winner or tie game
  checkForWinner();
  checkForTieGame();

  // Switch current player
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
}
```

Now your AI player can use the `click` method.

`click(document.getElementById("4"));` etc.

I recommend making the AI play its moves in the click event handler (thus, after the player has played their turn)

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  const playerMove = event.target;
  click(playerMove);
  const computerMove = chooseComputerMove();
  click(chooseComputerMove);
}

function chooseComputerMove() {
  // TODO: implement this method
  // calculate which square the AI should play on this turn,
  // return that HTML element
}
```